# how use pagiantion in mysql view table with symfony and doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

i have view table with adds name,and entity 
my entity code is :

```
/**

* @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
* @ORM\Table(name="adds")
*/
class Adds
{

private function __construct() {}

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"addList"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"addList"})
 */
private $subject;
```

and in my controller i have this:

```
   $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
   $dql   = "SELECT adds FROM AppBundle:Adds adds ";
   $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

    $c = count($paginator);
    foreach ($paginator as $post) {
        $this->dumpWithHeaders($post);
    }
```

but always $post itmes is [];

Comment: what does "dumpWithHeaders" do? can you add this also?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try with this :

```
  $dql   = "SELECT adds FROM App\Entity\Adds adds";
```

What result do you have?